# Pdf creation and Writing content inside - PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pypdf

I am reading text from one pdf recursively and doing some operation with the extracted text at each run  and  want to create a new pdf to save that edited text with each run ..
I tried below from PyPDF2..

```
import PyPDF2
output = PdfFileWriter()
pdf="pdfte.pdf"
Obj_pdfFile = open(pdf, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(Obj_pdfFile,strict = False)
pages=pdfReader.numPages
for page in range(pages):
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(page)
        pdf_text=pageObj.extractText()
        upper = pdf_text.upper()
        #print(pdf_text)
        output.addPage(input.getPage(upper)) . # I thought this will work but no use..
```

I know need to input "page" but basically looking how to save edited text in new pdf ... I know I am missing some code here that how to save in pdf etc but thats exactly what I need help, never worked with pdf..
Also, is there any better option to do this ?

Comment: Could you share the input PDF file?

Comment: @xilopaint Problem is with any of the pdf . You can try any pdf that you have ..

Comment: Sorry, but if you want me to test your code I ask you to share a sample PDF file.

Comment: @xilopaint Please let me know , how to share that , will do it.

Comment: Just share a download link.

Comment: https://www.cs.uky.edu/~keen/115/Haltermanpythonbook.pdf

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

PyPDF2 is amazing to handle pdf files as documents, but not as an editor. I wanted to do the same that you tried, but only made it posible with reportlab as many other answers here do. Note that here

> output.addPage(input.getPage(upper)) . # I thought this will work but no use.
>   upper is a string, and getPage() is expecting a page from 
>       PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffile).getPage(0)
>   Here is that worked for me on python 2.7:

```
    temp = StringIO()
    from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A6 #choose here your size
    can = canvas.Canvas(temp, pagesize=A6)
    can.drawString(10, 405, "Your string on this position")
    can.save()
    temp.seek(0)
    lector = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(temp)
    output.addPage(lector.getPage(0)) #your pypdf2 writter
```

now output is your pdf with the string attached, hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: Nice idea to create a temporary canvas, however `StringIO()` didnt work for me and had to use `BytesIO()` since canvas expects that